# Firefox: Moving the cursor past a link scrolls the page up

Tags: firefox

As in the title. Firefox 27.0.1.

This has been driving me nuts: I'll hover over something (say, a link in a google search result) and the page scrolls up slightly.

Nothing in the configuration strikes me as `scroll up on hovers` or `fail to center a link on the cursor, but scroll anyway`.

EDIT:

For the pedantic: I wish to disable this nonsense!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like interference of some script or style from some extension on the page. Try running [Firefox in safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) to troubleshoot the problem or simply [resetting Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems).